# running a windows service from jmeter

Tags: windows-services, jmeter

I am writing a jmeter script to perform DB functional testing. I have a Windows Service that runs every on X interval and it updates certain DB records when its done. I need to be able to run the windows service remotely and verify the DB changes.

Is it possible to run a windows service remotely say using `sc \\machine stop <service>` from jmeter?
If yes, how can I do this?

Appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: I am going to try it today. Have to update my 2.6 to 2.8 to use OS Process Sampler.

Comment: Jmeter 2.9 released already: http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi#binaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler).

For command like `sc SERVER_NAME stop SERVICE_NAME` it will be configured like:

[image]